# How to fix "× TypeError: Cannot read property 'pathname' of undefined" after adding NavLink?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am working at my firs NodeJS/ReactJS web project and I got stuck after adding `<NavLink>`. [This](https://bitbucket.org/danclaudiu95/nodejs-reactjs/src/master/netflix-dan/) is the link to my full project.

I am following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fs01JJIqfRk&t=1s) tutorial and I see that in `package.json` modules are newer than in video. I have

```
{
    "react": "^16.11.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.11.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
}
```

Code from my `header.js`:

```
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';

            <div className="header-container">
               <div className="header-top">
                    <img src={logo} alt=""/>
                    <NavLink className="signIn-btn">Sign In</NavLink>
               </div>
           </div>
```

I am working for my first NodeJS/ReactJS application and I am getting:

```
× TypeError: Cannot read property 'pathname' of undefined"
```

after adding `NavLink` to my `Header.js`.

Comment: Does my answer solve your problem? Instead of editing title and adding "solved", please consider accepting my answer.

Comment: yes, it works, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `to` prop.

Try this:

```
<NavLink className="signIn-btn" to="/">Sign In</NavLink>
```